# Bitbucket pipelines without container

Tags: php, lamp, bitbucket-pipelines

Can I create Bitbucket pipeline that will simple just pull code from repo and deploy it to web root folder. I don't use any kind of container, just LAMP stack.

Answer (score 0):

The code you put in a pipeline will run in a container created by Bitbucket anyway. If you use, for examle, SCP for deployments you can just find a very minimal image that has the tools you need (like [`buildo/docker-alpine-ssh`](https://hub.docker.com/r/buildo/docker-alpine-ssh) for SCP) and use it:

```
- step:
    name: Deploy
    image:
      name: buildo/docker-alpine-ssh
    script:
      - scp file user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

the idea of bitbucket pipelines is to create a docker instance where you can build the repo before deploying to your server.

you can push your build to you server via ssh atlassian/rsync-deploy

Answer (score 0):

You should create a docker instance before deploying to your server. to enable access to Docker daemon, you can either add docker as a service on the step

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - ...
        services:
          - docker
```